# Pandas csv - cleaning up data in the wrong column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I'm working with a dataset where some rows have a column missing, and the subsequent columns are wrongly moved into the missing column's place, so it might look like this:

```
              date    tap     time    count
0         20160730     on     02:30   415.0
1         20160730     on     02:30    18.0
2         20160730     on     02:30    24.0
3         20160730     on     02:30    31.0
4         20160730     on     13:30    64.0
...            ...    ...       ...     ...
169549    20170101  23:45        29     NaN
169550    20170101  23:45        34     NaN
169551    20170101  23:45        43     NaN
169552    20170101  23:45        42     NaN
169553    20170101  23:45        60     NaN
```

Notice how in the last 5 rows, the value for 'time' is in the 'tap' column, while the value for 'count' is in the 'time' column. This doesn't just happen in the last few rows but throughout the dataset.

I'm trying to make a function that does this:

```
for each item in the 'tap' column
   if item is neither 'on' or 'off', then
      the value of the 'count' column in that row takes on the value of the 'time' column
      the value of the 'time' column in that row takes on the value of the 'tap' column
      the value of the 'tap' column in that row is replaced by a string "N/A"
```

So hopefully the end result will look like this:

```
              date   tap    time    count
0         20160730    on    02:30   415.0
1         20160730    on    02:30    18.0
2         20160730    on    02:30    24.0
3         20160730    on    02:30    31.0
4         20160730    on    13:30    64.0
...            ...   ...      ...     ...
169549    20170101   N/A    23:45      29
169550    20170101   N/A    23:45      34
169551    20170101   N/A    23:45      43
169552    20170101   N/A    23:45      42
169553    20170101   N/A    23:45      60
```

So far I've only loaded the csv file...

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', dtype={
    'date': str,
    'tap': str,
    'time': str,
    'count': float})
```

I'm sure that I'm missing something really simple, but I've already spent hours on google and just couldn't find the right syntax to do this. Please let me know how to make this work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) with condition by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html), only necessary convert all columns to strings for avoid missing values for not matched dtypes (like in last column):

```
m = df['tap'].isin(['on','off'])
cols = ['tap','time','count']
df.loc[~m, cols] = df.loc[~m, cols].astype(str).shift(axis=1)
df['count'] = df['count'].astype(int)
print (df)
            date  tap   time  count
0       20160730   on  02:30    415
1       20160730   on  02:30     18
2       20160730   on  02:30     24
3       20160730   on  02:30     31
4       20160730   on  13:30     64
169549  20170101  NaN  23:45     29
169550  20170101  NaN  23:45     34
169551  20170101  NaN  23:45     43
169552  20170101  NaN  23:45     42
169553  20170101  NaN  23:45     60
```

If want assign new columns without shift:

```
m = df['tap'].isin(['on','off'])
df.loc[~m, ['time','count']] = df.loc[~m, ['tap','time']].to_numpy()
df.loc[~m, 'tap'] = np.nan
df['count'] = df['count'].astype(int)
print (df)
            date  tap   time  count
0       20160730   on  02:30    415
1       20160730   on  02:30     18
2       20160730   on  02:30     24
3       20160730   on  02:30     31
4       20160730   on  13:30     64
169549  20170101  NaN  23:45     29
169550  20170101  NaN  23:45     34
169551  20170101  NaN  23:45     43
169552  20170101  NaN  23:45     42
169553  20170101  NaN  23:45     60
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
wrong_vals = df['tap'].isin(['on', 'off'])
df.loc[~wrong_vals, 'time'] = df['tap']
df.loc[wrong_vals, 'tap'] = None
```